# Guidance on creating a server that has a group of threads to process requests

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I am 1000 pop emails that I have to pull emails from.

I want to create a service, that utilizes muliple threads so I can pull email from multiple pop3 servers at the same time (as oppose to a serialized process).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Description of ThreadPoolExecutor from API doc:

> **public class ThreadPoolExecutor extends AbstractExecutorService**
>
> An ExecutorService that executes each
>   submitted task using one of possibly
>   several pooled threads, normally
>   configured using Executors factory
>   methods.
>
> Thread pools address two different
>   problems: they usually provide
>   improved performance when executing
>   large numbers of asynchronous tasks,
>   due to reduced per-task invocation
>   overhead, and they provide a means of
>   bounding and managing the resources,
>   including threads, consumed when
>   executing a collection of tasks. Each
>   ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some
>   basic statistics, such as the number
>   of completed tasks.

Here is simple [tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/ThreadPoolExecutor.shtml) for understanding same.

Some more links to understand same:

http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a specific requirement for thrading a networked application, [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) may be of interest.

From the homepage:

> Apache MINA is a network application
>   framework which helps users develop
>   high performance and high scalability
>   network applications easily. It
>   provides an abstract · event-driven ·
>   asynchronous API over various
>   transports such as TCP/IP and UDP/IP
>   via Java NIO.